# Postgres SELECT with multiple select as

Tags: postgresql, select, postgis

I'm trying to use the output from two SELECT statements in a PostGIS function.

What is the correct syntax for doing this? I'm getting a syntax error at or near the second SELECT statement.

```
SELECT ST_Split(tracks, roads)
FROM
(
    SELECT * FROM (SELECT ST_Buffer(road_geom,50) FROM table1 WHERE a = '' AND b = '') as roads,
    SELECT * FROM (SELECT the_geom FROM table2 WHERE c = '' AND d = '') as tracks

)
```

Error output:

```
 ERROR:  syntax error at or near "SELECT"
 LINE 5:  SELECT * FROM (SELECT the_geom FROM table2...
     ^
********** Error **********
ERROR: syntax error at or near "SELECT"
SQL state: 42601
Character: 178
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Demonstrating one method of using a CTE:

```
WITH    roads as (SELECT ST_Buffer(road_geom,50) as road FROM table1 WHERE a = '' AND b = ''),
        tracks as (SELECT the_geom as track FROM table2 WHERE c = '' AND d = '')
SELECT ST_Split( (select track from tracks), (select road from roads) );
```

Docs at http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-with.html

Comment: Thanks for your quick and accurate reply.

Comment: One thing to note is that the `SELECTs` from the "roads" and "tracks" virtual tables (the clauses in the `WITH` block) -- if they could ever return more than one row the query will fail, so you should then add `LIMIT 1` to both of them (in the `WITH` clause I mean).

Comment: Yeah - I ended up wrapping the split in a loop. Thanks again for your help!